# Jenkins- Not getting desired options while using Active Choice and Active Choicec Reactive Parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

We have requirement to select Environment from Jenkins UI to run the feature files.

Different Environment Options: QA, UAT, PROD

On the basis of the Environment selection from drop-down, all the available tenants i.e. different servers associated with that Environment should be visible.

To achieve above purpose I've used "Active Choices Parameter" for Environment.

- Name: "Environment"
- Groovy Script: return ['QA','UAT']
- Fallback Script: return['error']
- Choice Type: Single Select

To select the server or tenant on the basis of Environment selection, I've used "Active Choices Reactive Parameter"

- Name: Tenants
- Groovy Script:

```
return ['http://node-1.nginx.portal.daa-1.can.qa.aws.abc.net/login':'CAN','http://node-1.nginx.portal.daa-1.wan.qa.aws.abc.net/login':'WAN']
} else if (Environment.equals("UAT")) {
return ['https://can.uat.daa.app/login':'CANUAT','https://blic.uat.daa.app/login':'BLIC']
}
 else if (Environment.equals("PROD")){
return ['http://node-1.nginx.portal.daa-1.can.qa.aws.abc.net/login':'CANPROD','http://node-1.nginx.portal.daa-1.blic.qa.aws.abc.net/login':'BLIC']
} else {
  return ["Unknown"]
}
```

- Fallback Script: return['error']
- Choice Type: Single Select

After applying and saving this configuration, I'm getting ERROR in the Tenants drop-down.
Seems making minor mistake but unable to catch it.

[Getting ERROR in the drop-down of Tenant Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ykP2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Environment should be prefaced with a '$' (as in `$Environment`) in the groovy script to signify it is a variable.

And did you specify the 'Referenced parameters' as 'Environment' in the Active Choices Reactive Parameter settings?:

```
referencedParameters: 'Environment',
```

You can test out your groovy script in the script console at http://your-jenkins-server/script